# choose from a list of strings as field value in models.py in django

Tags: django, django-models

Im trying to write a model for a character in my version od D&D and I want that the user could only choose from lists of strings which will be the dictionaries names

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db import models
import misaka
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
# Create your models here.

Races={
       'Dragonborn':{'attack':13,'deffence':12,'intelligence':12,'agility':12,'wisdom':13,'charisma':13},
       'Dwarf':{'attack':11,'deffence':14,'intelligence':14,'agility':10,'wisdom':15,'charisma':11},
       'Elf':{'attack':10,'deffence':8,'intelligence':15,'agility':13,'wisdom':15,'charisma':14},
       'Gnome':{'attack':15,'deffence':15,'intelligence':10,'agility':15,'wisdom':10,'charisma':10},
       'Half-Elf':{'attack':13,'deffence':10,'intelligence':13,'agility':14,'wisdom':12,'charisma':13},
       'Halfling':{'attack':12,'deffence':13,'intelligence':14,'agility':13,'wisdom':12,'charisma':11},
       'Orc':{'attack':15,'deffence':15,'intelligence':11,'agility':12,'wisdom':11,'charisma':11},
       'Human':{'attack':12,'deffence':12,'intelligence':13,'agility':13,'wisdom':13,'charisma':12}
}
Classes={
         'Barbarian':{'attack':6,'deffence':3,'intelligence':1,'agility':4,'wisdom':1,'charisma':1},
         'Bard':{'attack':2,'deffence':1,'intelligence':4,'agility':4,'wisdom':4,'charisma':4},
         'Cleric':{'attack':3,'deffence':2,'intelligence':4,'agility':1,'wisdom':4,'charisma':2},
         'Druid':{'attack':3,'deffence':2,'intelligence':3,'agility':2,'wisdom':3,'charisma':3},
         'Fighter':{'attack':6,'deffence':3,'intelligence':1,'agility':4,'wisdom':1,'charisma':1},
         'Monk':{'attack':2,'deffence':2,'intelligence':3,'agility':4,'wisdom':3,'charisma':2},
         'Paladin':{'attack':5,'deffence':5,'intelligence':2,'agility':1,'wisdom':2,'charisma':1},
         'Ranger':{'attack':4,'deffence':1,'intelligence':3,'agility':5,'wisdom':3,'charisma':1},
         'Rogue':{'attack':5,'deffence':1,'intelligence':1,'agility':7,'wisdom':1,'charisma':1},
         'Sorcerer':{'attack':2,'deffence':1,'intelligence':6,'agility':1,'wisdom':5,'charisma':1}
}

class Character(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='characters',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #Races
    #class
```

how do I use the "models." for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

The Right way to do this is to Create `Races` and `Classes` models and then provide values from those models for Character model.

```
class Race(models.Model):
    name = ....
    attack = ....
    .
    .

class ClassCh(model.Model):
    name = ....
    attack = ....
    .
    .


class Character(models.Model):
   raceList = Race.objects.all()
   classList = ClassCh.objects.all()

   user=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='characters',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
   race = models.ForeignKey(choices = raceList,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   classch = models.ForeignKey(choices = classList,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You can also avoid creating models for races and classes, but then you need to save the dictionary as a string

```
race = models.CharField(choices= RACES_LIST)
class = models.CharField(choices= CLASSES_LIST)
```